# Тернарные операторы не пропускают delay

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-ide

Всех приветствую.
Есть такой код:

```
int btn1 = 2;

int wb = 0;

uint8_t LED1pin = 0;

uint8_t LED2pin = 1;

void setup(void) {

#define fen2 wb==2?

#define RDS1 digitalWrite(LED1pin, LOW)

#define REN1 digitalWrite(LED1pin, HIGH)

#define REN2 digitalWrite(LED2pin, HIGH)

#define RDS2 digitalWrite(LED2pin, LOW)

#define SLE1 delay(1000);

}

void loop(void) {

if(digitalRead(btn1)==HIGH){

wb == 2;

}

  fen2 REN1 SLE1 REN2:RDS2 SLE1 RDS1;

}
```

Если убрать `SLE`, то всё работает нормально. Но мне нужна возможность установки задержки.
В `loop` будет находиться конфигурационный файл, в котором и будет записано, какое реле включать и какая будет задержка.

Что не так, не понимаю.

Comment: `fen2 REN1 SLE1 REN2:RDS2 SLE1 RDS1;` - это тот случай, когда автор очень хочет выстрелить себе в ногу.

Comment: `g++ -E` поможет разобраться

Comment: Дело, как всегда, в точке с запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Не так синтаксические конструкции. Вместо:

```cpp
#define fen2 wb==2?
#define RDS1 digitalWrite(LED1pin, LOW)
#define REN1 digitalWrite(LED1pin, HIGH)
#define REN2 digitalWrite(LED2pin, HIGH)
#define RDS2 digitalWrite(LED2pin, LOW)
#define SLE1 delay(1000);
```

нужно использовать следующее:

```cpp
#define FEN2 (wb == 2)
#define RDS1 digitalWrite(LED1pin, LOW);
#define REN1 digitalWrite(LED1pin, HIGH);
#define REN2 digitalWrite(LED2pin, HIGH);
#define RDS2 digitalWrite(LED2pin, LOW);
#define SLE1 delay(1000);
```

Внутри функции loop нужно использовать такой синтаксис:

```cpp
if (digitalRead(btn1) == HIGH) wb = 2;
  
if (FEN2) {
  REN1;
  SLE1;
  REN2;
  RDS2;
  SLE1;
  RDS1;
}
```

*Данный текст написан с участием ChatGPT. Если вы разбираетесь в этой теме и считаете что ответ неверен - оцените сообщение или отредактируйте. Как только появится возможность, все ответы будут отмечаться общими.*

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: Я неправильно понимаю, или, все же, у автора вопроса был тернарный оператор, и были написаны обе ветви условия, а в ответе только одна?